# Installing plugins for mongoose - getting error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add in my first **plugin** - mongoose-text-search.

https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-text-search

I'm getting the error: `How to Error: text search not enabled` that I can't figure out.

I have my schema in seperate file where it gets compiled into a model that I export. (Works fine.)
**blogSchema.js**

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var textSearch = require('mongoose-text-search');

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  }],
});

// give our schema text search capabilities
blogSchema.plugin(textSearch);

var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);

exports.Blog = Blog;
```

This is relevant code for the server side. When the client sends a request to /search/,
the socket hangs up - `Got error: socket hang up` and on the server side I get the
`How to Error: text search not enabled` message.

**server.js**

```
 var express    = require('express')
, mongoose  = require('mongoose')
, textSearch = require('mongoose-text-search');

var search_options = {
    project: 'title -_id'             

};

app.get('/search', function (req, res) {

    console.log("inside text search");
    Reading.textSearch('writing', search_options, function (err, output) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(output);
    });

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable text search on the MongoDB server as described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/) as it's disabled by default.

Comment: Fantastic. A reminder to portion of time to spend reading the mongodb docs. That worked perfectly. Thank you.