# Full text search with weight in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

As I find out, since version 3.8.9, mongoose support full text search. But I can't find a good documentation for it!
I want to do something like:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
    // Fields to index
    {
        animal:  "text",
        color:   "text",
        pattern: "text",
        size:    "text"
    },

    // Options
    {
        name: "best_match_index",

        // Adjust field weights (default is 1)
        weights: {
            animal: 5,  // Most relevant search field
            size:   4   // Also relevant
       }
    }
)
```

Can I do it with pure mongoose? Or I have to use some plugin like [mongoose-text-search](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-text-search)? How about without weight?
And how should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried calling [`index`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index) on the schema to add the text index?

Comment: I did it in schema as index: 'text', but I want to index on multiple fields as above example.

Comment: Don't declare it in your schema definition, _call_ the `index` method of your schema.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index

Comment: you mean
'schema.index({
    animal:  "text",
    color:   "text",
    pattern: "text",
    size:    "text"
})'
? What about weight? And does it make single index or 4 indexes?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Yes, you can use full text search in Mongoose >= 3.8.9. Firstly, a collection can have at most one text index (see [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index)). So, to define text index for [several fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/), you need compound index:

```js
schema.index({ animal: 'text', color: 'text', pattern: 'text', size: 'text' });
```

Now you can use [**$text** query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) like this:

```js
Model
    .find(
        { $text : { $search : "text to look for" } }, 
        { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
    )
    .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        // callback
    });
```

This will also sort results by relevance score.

As for [weights](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/), you can try to pass weights options object to [`index()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index) method (where you define compound index) (working at least with v4.0.1 of mongoose):

```js
schema.index({ animal: 'text', color: 'text', pattern: 'text', size: 'text' }, {name: 'My text index', weights: {animal: 10, color: 4, pattern: 2, size: 1}});
```

Comment: returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query

Comment: to define text index for several fields, you need compound index. Make sure you're defining compound index right.

Comment: Is this procedure documented somewhere? I'm trying to use text index with mongoose but it doesn't work. I have created a compound index, I have used the $text operator like your example, but the result is always an empty document.

Comment: see [$text doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) and [text search tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes-text/). What is your Mongoose version? (full text search works for ver >= 3.8.9)

Comment: Those doc links are for Mongo.  Is there anything for Mongoose itself?

Comment: With version 4.0.1 of mongoose, the weights options were operationnal.

Comment: @Mallen did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm trying to access the score property after I get the results in order to display them on my app, but for some reason I'm getting undefined. If I console.log the results array, I do see the score property under each object, but if I specifically try to access it, I get undefined. Any ideas why or how to correctly do this? thank you.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly for creating a index when using mongoose. Can you please let me know how to drop the index in mongoose ?

Answer (score 2):

As of MongoDB 2.6, a collection can have at most one text index (documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)). Therefore, you will not be able to do what you want with the current version of MongoDB. Really, for complicated text searching problems with requirements of different weights depending on the location of the match, you should consider a full-blown text searching solution like Solr or ElasticSearch.

As a workaround in MongoDB, you could tokenize the fields manually, store them as keyword arrays, and index them:

```
animal: ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jump", ..., "dog"]
```

then a query like

db.test.find({animal: {$in: ["brown", "shoes"]})

mimics text search. There are a few limitations of this approach like the manual work required to set it up, the fact that there will be no stemming to, e.g., match "dreaming" with "dream",  the fact that stopwords will not be removed like in a normal text index, and the absence of any weighting mechanism.

Comment: In fact I have just one text index with multiple fields.
The blow code is part of .getIndexes(). I did it with [mongoose-text-search](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-text-search), I'm looking for a pure mongoose version of it.

  `
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "_fts" : "text",
   "_ftsx" : 1
  },
  "ns" : "public-diary-dev.diaries",
  "name" : "full-search-index",
  "background" : true,
  "weights" : {
   "tags" : 1,
   "text" : 1,
   "title" : 1
  },
  "default_language" : "english",
  "language_override" : "language",
  "textIndexVersion" : 1
 }
`

Answer (score 1):

I found the following article that led me to the http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835
I dropped the index created in the top answer using the following

```
db.tablename.dropIndex({"indexname_text"})
```

I got the list of indexes with this command

```
db.tablename.getIndexes()
```

I then used the following to create the indexes

```
db.tablename.createIndex({"$**":"text"})
```

the following commands worked in Mongoose

```
model.find(
    {$text: {$search: "text you are searching for"}},
    {score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
    .sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}}
)
.exec(function(err, results) {
    `enter code here`if(!err){
    console.log('results ' + results);
}
else
{
    console.log(err);
}
});
```

Answer (score -5):

```
    var searchQuery=new RegExp('dam', 'i');
    var query = { firstName : searchQuery };
    Model.find(query ...
```

Comment: This answer is the bomb! I wasted the last two hours trying to add a text index to my schema and this simple-as-f**k answer is all I needed. Huzzah!

Comment: Yes, It is, but you can't create human-friendly query avoiding use the regular expressions.

Comment: Careful with this, as it could accidentally result in [regex denial of service vulnerability](https://medium.com/@liran.tal/node-js-pitfalls-how-a-regex-can-bring-your-system-down-cbf1dc6c4e02)

Comment: Fully agreed with BrotherDonkey ...Please post anwers with taking security in mind !