# Change the output/projection format of search query in a node js app with mongodb and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm implementing a search function for a node app with mongoose. I'm fairly new to *node.js* and *mongoose*. I implemented a search function following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714166/full-text-search-with-weight-in-mongoose). It works and gives me the results.

But the problem is it gives an array of ***whole objects***. All I need is ***titles*** and ***IDs***. Could anyone please suggest me how to get those.

this is my code

```
Model.find(
    { $text : { $search : req.params.searchtext }}, 
    {score : { $meta: "textScore" }}
)
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
.exec(function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
      return res.status(403).send({success: false});
    } else{      
      res.json({success: true, results: results});
    }

});
```

this is another code where I'm finding a similar list.

```
Model.find({
        'createdBy.id' : user._id
      },'title _id' ,function(err, result) { #callback};
```

but I cannot use `'title _id'` in the search function since the `$meta` sort key needs to be there for sort  the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the change the output by using mongoose [query api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html).

```
Model.find(
    { $text : { $search : req.params.searchtext }}, 
     {score : { $meta: "textScore" }}
)
.limit(20)
.select('textScore title _id description')
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
.exec(function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
      return res.status(403).send({success: false});
    } else{      
      res.json({success: true, results: results});
    }

});
```

all I had to do is just adding `select('textScore title _id description')` line.