# Index not found in mongodb createIndex while using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My `Shows` documents are like this

```
{
  _id: '',
  summary: 'The pink cat ate all the cake"
}
```

I am writing node js code using mongoose like this to have a `text index` on the `summary field`

```
exports.textIndex = async (req, res) => {
  try{

    await Shows.createIndexes({summary: "text"});
    
    const data = await Shows.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { $text: { $search: "pink cake" } }
      }
    ]);

    res.status(200).json({message: 'Success', data});

  }catch(e){res.status(500).json({message: e.message});}
};
```

But this gives a mongodb error  as such:

```
{
    "message": "text index required for $text query"
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714166/full-text-search-with-weight-in-mongoose